# More efficient way to import 100k+ .csv's into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 225 folders that contain ~107,000 .csv's that I want to do some conversion on then import into an already created pandas dataframe.

```
           Main Folder
               |
--------------------------------
|              |               |
subfolder1     sub2    ...    sub225
|              |               |
600 csv's     22 csv's      1400 csv's
```

My current code does what's needed with a smaller number of files (10k). However with 100k files it slows down massively and eventually crashes my jupyter notebook/chrome roughly half way through which I think is from a memory error (the code is also slow). My machine has 16GB RAM.

```
def data_loader(pair='XYZ'):

    df = get_df()
    path = r'D:\Sample\{}'.format(pair)

    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

    print(pair)

    df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)
    dfnew = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)

    # Perform data pre-processing that turns the 80k rows into 5 columns.

    return df


for i in range(len(pairs)):
    data_loader(pairs[i])
```

It outputs 5 columns for each subfolder and adds it to the current df so a total of 225x5 new columns added to the existing df.

```
df
original col1 | col2 | subfolder1 cols1|2|3|4|5 .. subfolder225 cols1|2|3|4|5
```

what would be a better way to implement this? Thanks.

Comment: if you don't have to use entire dataframe for processing the data then you can read chunk by chunk and perform operations

Comment: If your calculations / dataframe manipulations are fairly basic, then use `dask.dataframe` [part of blaze project]. Perform all your calculations lazily, then only move back to pandas when you need to output a subset of results. Is this viable for your use case?